# Gasless transactions

Tags: tezos-signer

I was looking for paymasters in Tezos and I noticed there is no one.

There were some old [announcements](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/ipgscu/meta_transactions_on_tezos/) from 2020 saying that Biconomy was gonna take care of it but they finally did not.

Then, I found this proposal : [TZIP-017](https://tzip.tezosagora.org/proposal/tzip-17/) talking about meta-txs the most know way on Evms to lavearage gasless txs. However it is still on Draft status since 2020.

My questions are:

- Can txs be sponsored by someone-else on Tezos?
- How? What is the standard for it?
- Is there any available service for this?

Other concern:

How can Tezos develop their Gaming Vertical (announced [here](https://tezos.foundation/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/Tezos_Foundation_Biannual_September_23.pdf)) if there is no strategy on how to handle web2 users?

Comment: Re: gaming and onboarding web2 users: A). The game can be fully or partially free-2-play with optional NFT purchases for extra content. This would allow anyone, web2 or web3, to onboard without needing funds. B). If users must own some NFT to participate in the game and you want to make it free, you can have a server side application mint NFTs and send it to users who sign up. User doesn't need any funds to receive an NFT. Free-to-play or registration-required are both traditional web2 means of onboarding users, that users will be used to and find easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions in your post, about things that are related, but different.

First, about the paymaster/gas station (to my knowledge they are the same thing, yes?): the Marigold team recently started working on a gas station API. This API lets users submit transactions, which are then posted by a 3rd-party (the API's account). Such transactions are sometimes called "relayed transactions". Additional conditions can be expressed to decide if such transactions should be accepted (i.e., the target contracts and entrypoints were allowed and paid for). Marigold also proposes a front-end (not public yet) to let a user provide credits for a set of contracts. Alternatively, the API project is still a little bit immature, but can be deployed by any project.

This means that transactions can be signed by a user who has no tez on their account (and whose account isn't even revealed). However, the transactions are, *in fine*, posted by the API's account. This means that the contracts have to be written with that difference in mind. They cannot, for instance, rely on the SOURCE or SENDER instructions, as typical FA contracts do. This is where TZIP 17 (Permit) comes handy: it extends FA2 and provides a trust-less, secure and decentralized way of creating assets that can be transferred in relayed transactions. Trust-less because the user signs a permit for a specific transfer (to a specific address), which can also be revoked. Secure, because it is signed by the user off-chain, and cannot be used in a different context, nor in replay attacks (using the same signature again). Decentralized (or, rather, censorship resistant), because anyone can post the permit on-chain, not just the aforementioned API. Still, the two can be used together to provide a better experience to users. If you're interested in developing a game, for instance, players can earn items as NFTs (already possible without gas station or TZIP 17); the game can also offer to transfer those NFTs to a given marketplace contract for them, and third-party developers can write new contracts that accept those NFTs, without special authorizations ("admin mode") in the contract.

For the sake of completeness, let's also mention that TZIP 17 has several technical shortcomings, but a new version will be publish soon; moreover, Marigold is also working on a proposal to update the Tezos protocol to support relayed transactions natively. It seems to me that it will make TZIP 17 obsolete, but new applications for permits can still be developed in the future (such as subscriptions).

You can [contact the Marigold team](https://www.marigold.dev/contact) if you need more information, if you want early access to the demo or if you have a specific use case in mind and want to make sure it is going to be supported.